# Access parent variable contents in PHP

Tags: php, oop

I'm trying to access the contents of a parent class in PHP but for some reason it doesn't seem to want to pull through. I'm very new to OOP, so if there are any suggestions, please let me know. Below is my code:

```
class baseQuery {
    public static $numbers = "(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 32, 39, 50, 52, 72, 109, 110, 850, 1839, 1968, 1969, 1970, 1972, 1973, 2364, 2365, 3009)";
}

class specificQuery extends baseQuery {
    public function __construct() {
        $numbers = $this->numbers;
    }
    public function test() {
        echo $numbers; //fails
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to access a static member, you need to use the following syntax:

```
self::$varname
```

You could do the same by using the actual class name instead of `self`. As far as php is concerned, your `test()` method is trying to access a variable named `$numbers` that you haven't declared. If you don't use the `$this->` or `self::` syntax, PHP assumes it's a local (or, if you're being really dangerous, a global) variable.

Answer (score 1):

You should read over ["Late Static Bindings"](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php). Basically you would access the numbers property using the static keyword.

```
class specificQuery extends baseQuery {
    public function test() {
        echo static::$numbers;
    }
}
```

I like using static over self because then if you set $numbers in a class that extends the original, it would be accessed rather than the base class.

Answer (score 0):

in the second class that extends the original one, you are setting a regular variable, you need to store it somewhere.

try to assign a new public variable in the second class, store the numbers to him and then display him in the function.

Answer (score 0):

```
class baseQuery {
    public static $numbers = "(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 32, 39, 50, 52, 72, 109, 110, 850, 1839, 1968, 1969, 1970, 1972, 1973, 2364, 2365, 3009)";
}
class specificQuery extends baseQuery {
    public function __construct() {}

    public function test() {
        echo self::$numbers; // works :)
    }
}
```